# How do I set home folder in Heroku system variable?

Tags: node.js, heroku, config, system-variable

I'm deploying a node.js app on Heroku dyno and using [config module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) that requires me to define a system variable `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` with the location of the `config` folder.

The `config` folder is located on my project's root.

I tried to define the system variable `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` using the following values, all failed:

```
./config
~/config
app/config
~/app/config
./app/config
$HOME/config
$HOME/app/config
```

I keep getting this error:

```
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:app/config
```

(replace `app/config` with any of the values above)

I manage to set a system variable, but its value is not pointing the right place.

What is the correct way to refer to the root of my tree when using a system variable in Heroku?

Comment: Assuming you can get the library to find that directory, how are you planning to populate it with configuration files? You should probably read about Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and the way it [recommends handling configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad...

Both answers are correct but didn't solve my issue.

The problem was that I used lowercase for my configuration file name while the `NODE_ENV` value was uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation - if `config` folder is in the root of your application you **should not need** to specify `$NODE_CONFIG_DIR` env variable.

---

### From node-config [documentation](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files):

Node-config reads configuration files in the './config' directory for the running process, typically the application root. This can be overridden by setting the `$NODE_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable to the directory containing your configuration files. It can also be set from node, before loading `Node-config`:

```
process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = __dirname + "/configDir/";
const config = require("config");
```

`$NODE_CONFIG_DIR` can be a full path from your root directory, or a relative path from the process if the value begins with `./` or `../.`

---

You could use above code to set it from your node code.

Answer (score 1):

You were close: `/app` is the correct path. You can verify it by running `heroku run bash`.